# How to use Praeteritum sollten in Indikativ and Konjunctiv?

Tags: standard-german, modal-verb, preterite, swiss-german

I know the meaning of Indikativ and Konjunctiv II through forum answers. Sorry, I don't have link now.
As per what I have read about the difference is :

Indikativ is something real and in present.
Konjunctiv II is unrealistic or something may not happen.

Having sollten verb in praetritum form in Indikativ is not making me understand that how can we say that Indikativ is only present then?

Same thing when using the sollten verb in Praeteritum form in Kojnuncktiv II , the below example I read does not sound unrealistic.

I read in book that Konjunctiv II as advice Ratschlaege.
Example: du solltest dich belohnen. ( This indeed sounds as advice and not some unrealistic thing )

What is the exact difference between Indikativ & Konjunctiv II and how can we use the same conjugated verb sollten in praeteritum form in both the cases?

Comment: There is no verb *sollten*.

Comment: @RHa Your criticism should probably be more explicit if it is to be understood. At least, I don't understand it; the post calls *sollten* a *form*, which it is.

Comment: Sorry for the terseness, but it's only a comment. The questions says "sollten verb in preteritum form" which is confusing at best, but seems to imply that *sollten* is a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the exact difference between Indikativ & Konjunctiv II

You answered that already yourself:

> Indikativ is something real and in present. Konjunctiv II is unrealistic or something may not happen.

The difference, in short, is that Indikativ describes a real scenario while Konjunktiv 2 describes an imaginary, hypothetical one. It can be an advice, or something unrealistic, as you said.

> Having sollten verb in praetritum form in Indikativ is not making me understand that how can we say that Indikativ is only present then?

I guess you misunderstood the meaning of present. Indikativ cannot only exist in present time, but describes something that is or was present (= realistic or real, happened or is the case).

Example:

```
Indikativ Präsens: Der Lehrer soll seine Schüler unterrichten. 
=> The teacher shall/ must teach his students.
Indikativ Präteritum: Der Lehrer sollte seine Schüler unterrichten.
=> The teacher needed to teach his students.
Konjunktiv 2: Der Lehrer sollte seine Schüler unterrichten.
=> The teacher should teach his students. (because at the moment, he is not).
```

*Sollte* in the second example means the teacher had to teach his students, it can be confused with Konjunktiv 2, that would be another meaning.

```
Sie sollten dorthin gehen.
=> Indikativ Präteritum: They were supposed to go there.
=> Konjunktiv 2: They should go there.
```

As you can see, *sollte(n)* can be both, Indikativ and Konjunktiv. It depends on the context.

> I read in book that Konjunctiv II as advice Ratschlaege. Example: du solltest dich belohnen. ( This indeed sounds as advice and not some unrealistic thing )

Again, Konjunktiv 2 does not only describe unrealistic situations but also those that simply are not present as of now (havent happened yet). So you should treat yourself. English is a bit similar in this case, you would not say *you shall treat yourself*.

Comment: Thank you so much for such wonderful detailed answer :)